# How can I make a request to a socket twice in Python?

Tags: python, file, sockets, websocket, request

I'm wondering how I can make a request to a socket twice after a socket `shutdown`.

When the client first connects it'll send the string `request` to request a file from the server. It'll then do something with the file and send back the finished result.

Namely:

1. Request file from server.
2. Do something with the file.
3. Send back the new file.

This is what I got so far:

**server.py**:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 3000))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    (c, addr) = s.accept()

    request = c.recv(1024)

    if(request == "request"):
        f = open("image.png", "rb")
        l = f.read(1024)
        while(l):
            c.send(l)
            l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
        print("Done sending")

    elif(request == "validate"):
        # echo back request
        c.send(c.recv(1024))

    c.close()
s.close()
```

**client.py**:

```
import socket
import sys

# connect to server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 3000))

# request file
s.send("request")

f = open("test.png", "wb")
l = s.recv(1024)

while(l):
    f.write(l)
    l = s.recv(1024)

f.close()

print("Done receiving")

s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
s.close()

# do something with the file
# ...

# send new file back
s.send("validate")
s.send("Hello, World") # dummy input just to see if it's working

s.close() # 's' has already been closed, but I don't know how I should make another request after 's.shutdown(...)'
```

This just what I got so far, so if it's completely wrong please let me know!

Comment: You can't close the socket and then send to it again. You'll either need to open a new connection to the server, or hold off on the `shutdown` until you've finished your work.

Comment: @rbrtl Alright. It connects successfully the second time, but the `elif` statement doesn't seem to work in the `server.py` file.

Comment: How do you know that it's connecting successfully for the second time? You don't have any logging around the second connection from the client, and the `elif` statement is never reached by the server because the client is no longer connected.

Comment: @rbrtl I didn't have it in the above example, but if you print something within the servers while loop you'll see it's being run twice. Also, I don't know if you got it, but that was when tried what you said.

Comment: Oh ok, so you've got the connection re-open and now the `s.send("validate")` isn't working? I think your problem there is that you're reading more data at the server than the client is sending, but I haven't actually tried it myself.

Comment: @rbrtl Yeah, the request variable concatenate `validate` and `Hello, World` to `validateHello, World`. Is it possible to wait for the connection to finish before sending the second request?

Answer (score 0):

Once a connection has been shutdown, and even more so once it has been closed, you must reopen the connection to the server (which is still listening) from the client. The following snippet demonstrates this:

**client.py**

```
import socket
import sys

# connect to server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 3000))

# request file
s.send("request")

f = open("test.png", "wb")
l = s.recv(1024)

while(l):
    f.write(l)
    l = s.recv(1024)

f.close()

print("Done receiving")

s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
s.close()

# do something with the file
# ...

# send new file back

s.connect(("localhost",3000)) # This will reconnect to the server and you should see the echo
s.send("validate")
s.send("Hello, World") # dummy input just to see if it's working

s.close() # 's' has already been closed, but I don't know how I should make another request after 's.shutdown(...)'
```